# How to keep values from a messy table based on string characteristics

Tags: string, awk, sed

I have a really difficult file.asv (values separated with @) that contains lines with un-matching columns.

Example:

```
name@age@city@lat@long
eric@paris@4.4283333333333331e+01@-1.0550000000000000e+02
dan@43@berlin@3.1366000000000000e+01@-1.0371500000000000e+02
london@@2.5250000000000000e+01@1.0538333000000000e+02
```

Latitude and Longitude values are pretty consistent. They have 22 or 23 characters (depending on the positive (absent) and negative sign), and always with scientific notation. I would like to keep only latitude and longitude from each line.

Expected output:

```
lat@long
4.4283333333333331e+01@-1.0550000000000000e+02
3.1366000000000000e+01@-1.0371500000000000e+02
2.5250000000000000e+01@1.0538333000000000e+02
```

Headers are not totally necessary, I can add them later. I could also work with separated latitude and longitude outputs, and then paste them together. Any sed or awk command I could use?

Comment: Please provide the expected output for the above file

Comment: @fibar see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to select fields using regular expression

```
$ cat ll.awk

function rep(c, n,    ans) { # repeat `c' `n' times
    while (n--) ans = ans c
    return ans
}

function build_re(  d, s, os) { # build a regexp `r'
    d = "[0-9]" # a digit
    s  = "[+-]" # sign
    os = s "?" # optional sign

    r = os d "[.]" rep(d, 16) "e" s d d # adjust here
    r = "^" r "$" # match entire string
}

function process(   sep, line, i) {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i ++ ) {
        if (!($i ~ r)) continue # skip fields
        line = line sep $i; sep = FS
    }
    if (length(line)) print line
}

BEGIN {
    build_re()
    FS = "@"
}

{ # call on every line of input
    process()
}
```

Usage:

```
$ awk -f ll.awk file.txt 
4.4283333333333331e+01@-1.0550000000000000e+02
3.1366000000000000e+01@-1.0371500000000000e+02
2.5250000000000000e+01@1.0538333000000000e+02
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="@"} {print $(NF-1),$NF}' file
```

Here,

- `OFS` - Output Field Separator
- `FS` - Input Field Separator
- `NF` - Number of Fields

Assuming that `latitude` and `longitude` always be a last fields. `$NF` and `$(NF-1)` will print last two fields.

**Test:**

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="@"} {print $(NF-1),$NF}' file
lat@long
4.4283333333333331e+01@-1.0550000000000000e+02
3.1366000000000000e+01@-1.0371500000000000e+02
2.5250000000000000e+01@1.0538333000000000e+02
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple `grep` would do, assuming `-o` option is present

```
$ grep -o '[^@]*@[^@]*$' file.asv
lat@long
4.4283333333333331e+01@-1.0550000000000000e+02
3.1366000000000000e+01@-1.0371500000000000e+02
2.5250000000000000e+01@1.0538333000000000e+02
```

Answer (score 0):

One more in Gnu awk using `gensub`:

```
$ awk '{print gensub(/(.+)((@[^@]+){2})$/,"\\2","g",$0)}' file
@lat@long
@4.4283333333333331e+01@-1.0550000000000000e+02
@3.1366000000000000e+01@-1.0371500000000000e+02
@2.5250000000000000e+01@1.0538333000000000e+02
```